# What happens to Indrani?

Tags: indra, swarga

If being an Indra is just a post, what happens to Indrani(wife of Indra), after the current Indra's post is removed? Will she continue to be the wife of the next Indra too?

Answer (score 2):

> Shachi (Sanskrit: शची; also known as Indrani (queen of Indra), Aindri,
>   Mahendri, Pulomaja and Poulomi

It is said that unlike other goddesses, she possess an independent character of her own. Unlike most of the goddess wives who are known by their husband's name like Rudrani, Varuni (wife of Varun), Saranya (wife of Sun), **Indra is probably the only god who is known to be after his wife's name as well;** hence he was often referred as Shachipati—meaning master of shakti/power, or ShachiVat (possessor of Shachi).

According to the Rig Veda, ***Shachi is considered a most fortunate female for Indra granted her immortality***. It is said that he chose her over all of the other goddesses because of Her magnetic attractions.

> As per the Rig Veda, Indrani is considered to be the most fortunate
>   female as Lord Indra was granted immortality. ‘Among all females
>   Indrani is the most fortunate; for her husband shall not at any future
>   time die of old age’. Not everyone successively attains to the throne
>   of Lord Indra. It is a perpetual office as Indra is immortal. Many
>   kings and queens come and go, but by the very nature of Indra’s
>   immortality Indrani also continues as perpetual queen.

So there are two things we can conclude:

1. Indra granted her immortality.
2. Since Indra is immortal (and so is Indrani) they are bound to be together forever, also because they are husband & wife and we marry a person not the post he/she holds.

References [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shachi) and [2](http://vedicgoddess.weebly.com/goddess-vidya-blog/goddess-indrani-by-yogi-ananda-saraswathi)

Comment: As for *Indra being known after His wife*, even Narayana is called LakshmiKaanta Shiva is called ParvatiVallabha et cetera. In fact all Gods are known by name of their consort. Like Shakti is called ShivaPriyaa, and Shiva is called Gauriisha, Lakshmi is called HariPriyaa and Narayana as RamaaKaanta.

Comment: Yes, Besides Sachi didn't marry with post but instead she did marry with person who is sitting on post. So post stay or loose she will be wife of person since people marry with person, not with any designation.